# Raiz com indice - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como faço por exemplo para calcular a raiz sétima (7) de de 1,17 em JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

Exemplo abaixo:

```js
var raizSetimaDe1_17 = Math.pow(1.17, 1.0 / 7);

alert("O valor da raiz sétima de 1,17 é " + raizSetimaDe1_17);
```

Comment: @LINQ valeu pelo edit.